# Can a table be added to a replication Db which isn't part of the original Db?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to build a WinForms app that allows the user to fill out a form for our company while keeping it clean and standardized. As part of this project, I have created a replication from our production Db with only the tables for clients and client contacts. I need those tables available to the App so it can pull current client information for this form. I wanted to add another table to the replication that is not from the original Db that will take all the information added for the form. I guess I don't **need** it, but I was wondering if it was possible and, if so, will it break anything.

I can already hear some of you guys reading this saying, why don't you just add another table to the production Db. Well, I thought of that but, the App that is bound by that Db is very strict and runs a check every time the app is launched to make sure the Db hasn't been corrupted. If it finds a new table has been added, I'm sure it wouldn't work. Also, I hear some of you shouting at your monitors, "Why do you want this table as part of the Replication, Why not just house it on a different Db that won't affect your precious app?" And to those people I would say, I just thought of that. But, I am trying to make something lightweight that can be put on a lot of computers without much over head or back end. Thank you in advance for considering this problem.

Comment: What type of replication are you using? Articles can be included/excluded from publishers. Only articles in the subscription will be re-created on snapshot. Tables outside of your subscription will not interfere with replication.

Comment: @RossBush Transnational replication

Comment: If you are using one way tx replication, by the sound of it you are, you might consider making the replicated articles read-only as not to break your subscription.

Comment: It is possible to replicate an indexed view as a table. To do this, you would need to be able to create an indexed view based on the table inside your database. If this is possible, look at [this Microsoft BOL link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/publish-data-and-database-objects?view=sql-server-2017#publishing-views)